# How to fix Object Position in Canvas Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am implementing Canvas Drag and Drop Functionality in ReactJs. Problem is that the Object is always centered under the pointer. To initiate the drag’n’drop can we mousedown anywhere on the Object. If do it at the edge, then the Object suddenly “jumps” to become centered. Here is my Code...

```
     var rect = this.props.refs.svg.getBoundingClientRect();
     const { xUnit, yUnit } = CanvasDimensions(
      rect,
      this.props.canvasWidth,
      this.props.canvasHeight,
      e.clientX,
      e.clientY
    );

    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      var tempELement = this.props.conceptItemsList.findIndex(
        item => item.sys.id === this.state.DraggingId
      );
      var ElementWidth = this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].width;
      var ElementHeight = this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].height;

      if (this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].__typename === "Text") {
        ElementWidth =
          this.props.refs[this.state.DraggingId].getBoundingClientRect().width /
          xUnit;
      }
      const { X, Y } = CanvasDimensions(
        rect,
        this.props.canvasWidth,
        this.props.canvasHeight,
        e.clientX,
        e.clientY,
        ElementWidth,
        ElementHeight
      );
      if (
        Y + this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].height >
        this.props.CanvasHeight
      ) {
        this.props.setCanvasHeight(
          Y + this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].height
        );
      }
      this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].x = X;
      this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement].y = Y;
      this.props.SetDragging(this.props.conceptItemsList[tempELement]);
}


export const CanvasDimensions = (
  rect,
  canvasWidth,
  canvasHeight,
  clientX,
  clientY,
  width = ImageWidth,
  height = ImageHeight
) => {
  const xUnit = rect.width / canvasWidth;
  const yUnit = rect.height / canvasHeight;

  const canvasX = clientX - rect.left;
  const canvasY = clientY - rect.top;

  var X = canvasX  / xUnit;
  var Y = canvasY  / yUnit;




   X = X < width / 2 ? X - X : X - width / 2;
   Y = Y < height / 2 ? Y - Y : Y - height / 2;
  if (X + width / 1.7 > canvasWidth) {
    X = X - width / 2;
   }
  return { X, Y, xUnit, yUnit };
};
```

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca can you please solve my problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I just fixed your title. I don't know the answer.

Comment: ok no problem @Federico klez Culloca